# Discord JDA loadMembers().get() not working for me :(

Tags: discord, bots, discord-jda

I want to get information about the number of all members of my discord.
Example:

```
Guild guild= jda.getGuildById(GUILD_ID);
List<Member> members = guild.loadMembers().get();
```

I enabled GatewayIntent.GUILD_MEMBERS:

```
jda = JDABuilder.createDefault(botToken)
                    .enableIntents(GatewayIntent.GUILD_MEMBERS)
                    .setMemberCachePolicy(MemberCachePolicy.ALL)
                    .build();
```

In application dashboard under the Privileged Gateway Intents section, i set enable SERVER MEMBERS INTENT and MESSAGE CONTENT INTENT.
[image]
Unfortunately it still doesn't work. Error message:

```
[main] INFO net.dv8tion.jda.api.JDA - Login Successful!
[JDA MainWS-ReadThread] INFO net.dv8tion.jda.internal.requests.WebSocketClient - Connected to WebSocket
[JDA MainWS-ReadThread] INFO net.dv8tion.jda.api.JDA - Finished Loading!
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Blocking operations are not permitted on the gateway thread
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.utils.concurrent.task.GatewayTask.get(GatewayTask.java:96)
    at Main.onMessageReceived(Main.java:277)
```

I found in the documentation:

> [You MUST NOT use blocking operations such as Task.get()!](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/Guild.html#loadMembers())
> [The response handling happens on the event thread by default.](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/Guild.html#loadMembers())

But how do I check it and apply it?

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a callback:

```java
guild.loadMembers().onSuccess(members -> {
  // run your code inside here
  for (Member member : members) {
    System.out.println(member.getEffectiveName());
  }
});
```

You can also use `loadMembers(...)` as an async for-loop:

```java
guild.loadMembers(member -> System.out.println(member.getEffectiveName()));
```

If you enable guild member chunking (not recommended for larger bots of more than 100 guilds), you can use `getMembers()` instead:

```java
jda = JDABuilder.createDefault(botToken)
                    .enableIntents(GatewayIntent.GUILD_MEMBERS)
                    .setChunkingFilter(ChunkingFilter.ALL)
                    .setMemberCachePolicy(MemberCachePolicy.ALL)
                    .build();
```

```java
List<Member> members = guild.getMembers();
```